# JavaScript Credit Card Allowance not working

Tags: javascript

**When I run the following code:**

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
    if (income >= 100) {
        return console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
    }
    else {
        return console.log("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
    }
};
creditCheck("75");
creditCheck("125");
creditCheck("100");
```

**I get:**

```
Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.
You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.
You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.
Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.
```

Why do the variables not give the correct output?

Comment: How are you getting a fourth line in your console?

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: the code works fine - your output comes from a different code.

Comment: That fourth line shouldn't be there, you must be calling `creditCheck` again somewhere. The first three lines of output are correct for the values `75, 125, 100` so I don't think that there's actually a problem with the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you've posted in your question is NOT the output of the JavaScript console but the one of [codeacademy.com editor](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4#) thus making for us impossible to understand which was the problem.

You should change completely your question. However, using this code will work fine.

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
    if (income >= 100) {
        return ("You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.");
    }
    else {
        return ("Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.");
    }
};
creditCheck("75");
creditCheck("125");
creditCheck("100");
```

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, `income` being a string isn't making a difference.

Comment: agreed. The code works fine. I'll update the answer as soon as the OP will post more code for us to solve.

Comment: First of all, what does parseFloat() do (I am a beginner)? Second, as I stated above, that is the entire code. I am trying to use functions with an if/else statement as practice, because I am just starting out. Why am I getting 4 outputs if I only called on creditCheck 3 times?

Comment: Wrong. The code does output just 3 lines, as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/zNARj/ - you're probably missing some lines of code as someone already pointed out. Please update your answer with the full code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
creditCheck("75");
```

Instead, use

```
creditCheck(75);
```

With the quotation marks, you are passing in a string to the method. You want to pass in a number. However, in this case it does not matter as JavaScript is automatically converting it. You are probably missing something in your question; please post your full code and output.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference here.

Comment: @Blender Yes, I actually just noticed that. The OP is missing something in his or her question...

Comment: That is the entire code. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Everything should turn out fine, correct?

Comment: @AndrewGraber It is most definitely not the entire code. Why do you get four outputs, then?

Comment: That's what I asked on the second reply. I'm not sure.

Comment: @AndrewGraber That fiddle gives only 3 lines.

Comment: are you sure? it gives me 4 on the one I'm using. I'll upload a screenshot.

Comment: http://s1287.photobucket.com/user/Andrew_Graber/media/problem_zpsb988f7d0.png.html there's the screenshot.

Comment: The error your reporting may not be reproduced on our machines, how do you expect us to solve it? Please post a link to the website in the screenshot or click "save and submit" and share it here.

Comment: I can't exactly give a link. It is stored on my file on a website. I am using their custom editor to create this that only shows up for the certain page.

Comment: go here: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4# and copy paste the code from the fiddle.

Comment: yes, see my updated answer - you should change your question completely but I've fixed your problem.